# How to get a subset of data with conditions imposed?

Tags: r, subset, sampling

Suppose we have an expenditure data of the company where we have different expenditure values associated with different projects. How can we take a sample such that the sum of expenditure in the sample in certain proportion (say 80%) of the original total expenditure (population data)?Please help!

Comment: So you have a column with expenditure and you want a sample that includes enough entries so that the sum of the sample column will be 80% of the sum of the original column?

Comment: Order the data randomly, then take the first n rows where the cumulative sum of expenditure is greater than or equal to 80% of the total expenditure

Comment: can you please help me with the code for cumulative sum so that i can get the first rows with cumulative sum 80% of the total sum?
it would be of great help!

Comment: Also i have to make sure that the variables original proportion of expenditure remains the same in the sample. How should we get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting seed for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(12345)
```

Creating some sample data, with 100 projects:

```
dat <- data.frame(proj = 1:100,
                exp = sample(100:1000, 100, replace = TRUE))
totalexp <- sum(dat$exp)
```

Randomly ordering the data

```
ord <- sample(1:nrow(dat),nrow(dat))
dat <- dat[ord,]
```

Add the percentage of total expenditure for each project:

```
dat$exp.prop <- dat$exp/totalexp
```

Calculate cumulative sum for these proportions:

```
dat$exp.cumsum <- cumsum(dat$exp.prop)
```

Find the index of the project where the cumulative sum first crosses the 80% threshold, and take your project sample as all the projects before that index:

```
proj.sample <- dat$proj[1:(which(dat$exp.cumsum>0.80)[1]-1)]

proj.sample
 [1]  30  62  96  60  51  86  97  81  24  20  55  35  67  34  69  77  83  49   1  26  45
[22]  41   7  53  54  61  70  14  21  90   3  47  56  80  63  57  88  12  78  50  32  79
[43]  13  36   9  85  76  27  48  19  42  28  39  17  10  65  31  98  64  25 100  92  33
[64]  44  73  18  87   6  71  58  40  38  72  68  46  43  95  22
```